# Chrome extension: Access to variables of a background.js from a popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If I'm using [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage), I can access variables of the background.js like this:

background.js:

```
var transfer = 'some text';
```

popup.js:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().transfer
```

But [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) says I get only a window object (but maybe 'JavaScript' before 'window' means something...). How can I access background variables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the word 'javascript' before window does mean that its returning the javascript file(page) background.js

For ease of access at the top of my `popup.js` file I do this:

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); //do this in global scope for popup.js
```

then you can do this:

```
background.transfer;
```

Since you typically have to access your background page a lot, this just makes life easier all around.