# How to access variables from background.js to pop up in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, browser-extension

in chrome extension, I am creating a new html page as popup through background.js. Check the background.js code below,

```
 chrome.contextMenus.create({
title: "share this",
contexts: ["selection"],
onclick: myFunction
```

});

```
var test0 = "Testing content Outside the myfunction";

function myFunction(data) {
  var theSelection = data.selectionText;
      console.log(theSelection);

      chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, "lastFocusedWindow":true}, function(tabs) {
              var sourceURL = tabs[0].url;

                                chrome.windows.create({
                  url: chrome.runtime.getURL('redirect.html'), type: 'popup'},
              function(tab)
                            {

                               });
                return record;
            })

    }
```

I have gone through getbackgroundpage function given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572595/chrome-extension-access-to-variables-of-a-background-js-from-a-popup-js). I am able to access variable test0 with it but not sourceURL (as it is not in window scope).

by redirect popup window code is below,

```
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var sourceURL = bg.sourceURL;
var testvariable = bg.test0;
```

sourceURL is undefined.

Not getting a clue on how to define variables as global so that access in popup.

is there any better way, we can do it?

Comment: Use messaging or chrome.storage.local or localStorage or another global variable.

Comment: How to use global variable option. Much appreciate if give the syntax.

Comment: test0 is a global variable.

Answer (score -1):

Dude , try to use [Gogle message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) .

Little example from link before

> BackgroundScript

```
 var myFunc = function(){
 //some code
 }
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.messageType == "callSomeFunc") {
            myFunc();
            sendResponse({
                status: "Function myFunc called."
            });
        }
        //use return true for async response
        return true;
    });
```

> contentScript

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        messageType: "callSomeFunc"
    },    
    function(response) {
        // response contain {status: "Function myFunc called."}
        console.log(response);    
    });
```